# How to measure widget width and check for fit in container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I have a list of Widgets that I want to display in non-scrollable horizontal layout.

In the example below, I have 5 Widgets, 2 of them are fully displayed and the other 3 do not fit, hence the '+3' label.

[image]

I do not mind if there is some empty space after the label, but the important thing is that we only display Widgets that fully fit in the row.

I guess the main problem is how can I test that a Widget fits based on it's width into a row?

I thought about `VisibilityDetector`, but I will ended up rendering all widgets, then removing the ones that are not 100% visible, and the entire logic seems quite flawed for this use case.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do the item having same width? Also, is it just about text?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no and no. The text can vary in length and the widget I want to use will contain multiple other widgets and not only text. Sorry if I simplified the example too much.

Comment: use `CustomMultiChildLayout` - the docs say: "CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets"

Comment: @pskink thanks for the pointer. I will be exploring this as it seems quite a good fit for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try my version:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // widget
    List<GlobalKey> keys = [];
    var widgets = List.generate(25, (index) {
      GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
      keys.add(globalKey);
      return FilterChip(
        key: globalKey,
        label: Text("asdasasd"),
      );
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AppBar'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          OverRow(
            keys: keys,
            widgets: widgets,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverRow extends StatefulWidget {
  OverRow({Key key, this.keys, this.widgets}) : super(key: key);
  List<GlobalKey> keys = [];
  List<Widget> widgets = [];

  @override
  State<OverRow> createState() => _OverRowState();
}

class _OverRowState extends State<OverRow> {
  int overIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      for (var i = 0; i < widget.keys.length; i++) {
        final box = widget.keys[i].currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        final pos = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
        var over = pos.dx + box.size.width > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        if (over) {
          overIndex = i;
          setState(() {});
          return;
        }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
        children: overIndex == -1
            ? widget.widgets
            : [
                ...widget.widgets.take(overIndex).toList(),
                Container(
                  child: Text("+${widget.widgets.skip(overIndex).length}"),
                )
              ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

EDIT: Included dynamic width based in label length

Try this, with defined width of item container and the +label or with dynamic calculating the width based on font size.

Change useFixedWidth to true or false if you want dynamic or static width.

Example in a Stateless widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double itemWidth = 100; //maxwidth if item container
  final double labelWidth = 40; //maxWidth of +label

  List<String> items = List.generate(
      10, (index) => 'Name ${index + 1}'); //replace with a real list of items
  final bool useFixedWidth =
      false; // define if want to calculate dynamic with of each item
  final double letterWidth =
      12; // defined width of a letter || change depending on font size

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      int totalItems = items.length;
      int maxDisplayItems = 0;
      List<double> dynamicItemsWidth = []; //if want to use dynamic width

      if (useFixedWidth) {
        //if want to use fixed width
        maxDisplayItems =
            (((constraints.maxWidth - labelWidth) / itemWidth).floor()).clamp(
                0, totalItems); //check how many items fit including the +label

      } else {
        //if want to calculate based on string length
        dynamicItemsWidth = items
            .map((e) => e.length * letterWidth)
            .toList(); //calculate individual item width

        double _acumWidth = 0.0;
        for (var width in dynamicItemsWidth) {
          _acumWidth = _acumWidth + width;
          if (_acumWidth < (constraints.maxWidth - labelWidth)) {
            maxDisplayItems++;
          }
        }
      }

      bool showPlusSign =
          maxDisplayItems < totalItems; //check if all items can be shown
      return Row(children: [
        Row(
            children: List.generate(maxDisplayItems, (index) {
          return SizedBox(
              height: itemWidth,
              width: useFixedWidth ? itemWidth : dynamicItemsWidth[index],
              child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.red,
                  //width: itemWidth,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Name ${index + 1}'))));
        }).toList()),
        if (showPlusSign)
          SizedBox(
              width: labelWidth,
              height: itemWidth,
              child: Center(child: Text('+${totalItems - maxDisplayItems}')))
      ]);
    });
  }
}
```

shows this dynamic layout for 10 items:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to use LayoutBuilder. However the main problem that I had was that the width of the label is unknown, as the text can vary in length. Your solution assumes I know this upfront but really I don't.

Comment: Check the edit I did above. Now you can use dynamic or static width

Comment: I believe your description should be more specific, we need to know what each "Name #" section will contain if its not only text. but with the calculated dynamic width in the code above you can fit any widget inside the container of each item in my code keeping the text visible everytime, so you will have to experiment, or elaborate more about the end result you want beacuse the posibilities are endless.

Comment: Hey thanks for your edit. However, I see that you are still hardcoding things, in this second case, the letter width, which obviously will vary on character bases, font, size, etc. The question is quite specific as I did always mentioned 'Widget', not text nor anything else. The solution should be based on the calculation of the size of *any* type of widget, not Text based. This is about learning how to make this kind of layouts in general, not how to put text next to each other. Thanks again.